# Ionic 3 - How to disable scroll with default property without overflow:hidden

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have tried several methods to disable scroll.

Is there any property for ionic3 like `scroll="false"` available in `ionic 3` for `scroll-content`?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Disable scrolling of `scroll-content` meaning it is `overflow:hidden`

Comment: I am working with a multiple tabs structure for Ex. A main tabs will be fixed and will open other tabs inside it. I only want scroll inside inner tabs "CONTENT ONLY". The inner tabs will also need to be fixed

Answer (score 1):

There is **no such method** as per my knowledge.

This works for me.Sorry, this is a hack :)

*.html*

```
<ion-content>
  <span ion-fixed class="full-size-content">
     //html content
  </span>
</ion-content>
```

*.scss*

```
.full-size-content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answer :) but please let me know if there is any other options available (as this is a hack)

Comment: Sorry, There is no official way to do this yet :(

Comment: No prb! Thanks for the efforts :)